# Inno Setup: How do you prevent user from selecting "root" group?

Tags: inno-setup

How do I prevent a user from selecting the group to be the root of the start menu so that the group has to go to its own folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it seems that I was wrong. It does not seem that you can select the root of the Start menu anyhow. Or were you able to?

Comment: I'll post that as the answer just so others who may see the other thread have the answer.

Comment: I believe it would be better if you delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select the root with the current versions which makes it (more) safe to use wildcards with `{group}`.